# How to parse .obf file in objective c iphone sdk ? anyone have idea?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing

I want to parse a .obf file using Objective-C (iOS SDK)? Does anyone have experience reagarding this? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what an ".obf file" is: contents, patterns, a sample of the file, etc.

Comment: `.obf` is the "Osmand Binary Format", and comes from the `osmand` framework, which is for "Map Viewing & Navigation based on Open Street Maps for mobile devices." On their Google Code page, it looks like they have a fairly extensive loader, but its written in java. You could try porting it, or just look it over to see how the file is formatted. It also looks like `.obf` is related to ProtoBuf.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Protocol Buffer format.  The specification is here: http://code.google.com/p/osmand/source/browse/DataExtractionOSM/src/osmand_odb.proto

You'll probably want to use the Objective-C Protocol Buffer compiler and library: http://code.google.com/p/metasyntactic/wiki/ProtocolBuffers